jq merge 2 rows to 1
{
  "field": "@timestamp",
  "value": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.426"
}
{
  "field": "@message",
  "value": "Started-1"
}
{
  "field": "@timestamp",
  "value": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.427"
}
{
  "field": "@message",
  "value": "Started-2"
}

Edited to show that the JSONs are repeating block
I have JSONs above which need to be merged as below. Please help
[
  {
    "@timestamp": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.426",
    "@message": "Started-1"
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.427",
    "@message": "Started-2"
  }
]


You can use the from_entries function, which does exactly what you want, but it requires the future key's name in a field called key or name. Thus, first transform the objects to meet this requirement (the value field can stay as-is):
jq -s 'map({key: .field, value}) | from_entries'

{
  "@timestamp": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.426",
  "@message": "Started"
}

Demo

In the edited question, you want to apply from_entries to pairs of objects from the stream. _nwise(2) can bundle them into arrays of two. Also, to capture the output into an array, use brackets around the filter:
jq -s 'map({key: .field, value}) | [_nwise(2) | from_entries]'

[
  {
    "@timestamp": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.426",
    "@message": "Started-1"
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.427",
    "@message": "Started-2"
  }
]

Demo

I like your approach. It's crisp and better than what I wrote. Thanks.

the JSONs is output of a aws cli command.
How could I achieve same if the '@'timestamp and '@'message block repeat in the stream

file1.json

{
  "field": "@timestamp",
  "value": "2024-08-20 23:00:13.426"
}

file2.json

{
  "field": "@message",
  "value": "Started"
}

jq -s '.[0].value as $timestamp | .[1].value as $message | {"@timestamp": $timestamp, "@message": $message}' file1.json file2.json



